# Multiple Relations Trouble

Tags: templating, relations, relatedto

I'm having trouble setting entries with multiple relations.

during testing I've hard coded the theme to 1 specific category

```
{% set themeID = "12309" %}
{% set theme = craft.categories.group('survivorThemes').id(themeID).all() %}
```

I then set this

`{% set survivors = craft.entries.section('authors').includeInRecollection('1').relatedTo({ sourceElement: relatedAssetIds }).orderBy('lastName asc').limit(null).all() %}`

and then a for loop

```
        {% for survivor in survivors %}
            {% set relatedIds = "" %}






{# this should work but doesn't #}
            {% set entries = 
                craft.entries.section('survivorAssets')
                .relatedTo('and', { targetElement: themeID },{ targetElement: survivor })
                .orderBy('assetOrder')
                .all() 
            %}  

{# this should also work but doesn't #}
            {% set testEntries = craft.entries.section('survivorAssets')
                .relatedTo('and', {targetElement: survivor, field: 'relatedSurvivor'}, {targetElement: themeID, field: 'themes'})
                .orderBy('assetOrder')
                .all()  %}






          <div class="testing" style="background:red;color:#fff;padding:30px;margin:30px;">

            survivor: {{ survivor.title }} <br>

            theme: {{ themeID }} <br>

            ids: {{ relatedIds}} <br>

            total results: {{ entries|length }} <br>

            test total: {{ testEntries|length }} <br>

          </div><!-- /.testing -->


                {% if entries|length %}
                    {% set activeClass = " active" %}
                    {% for entry in entries %}
                        {% set relatedIds = relatedIds ~ entry.id %}
                        {% if not loop.last %}
                            {% set relatedIds = relatedIds ~ "," %}
                        {% endif %}

              more code here
                        
                    {% endfor %}                    
                {% endif %}
                
        more code here
        
        {% endfor %}
```

In the above loop I expect the entries to have results but I get zero results in my test div.

> survivor: Judy Abrams
>
> theme: 12309
>
> ids:
>
> total results: 0
>
> test total: 0

Have confirmed that there should be 3 entries that match the **entries** or **testEntries** variable by looking at specific entries in the control panel.

Comment: Does this work? `{% set entries = craft.entries.section('survivorAssets').relatedTo(['and',{ targetElement: theme },{ targetElement: survivor }]).orderBy('assetOrder').all() %}`

Comment: @Oli Thank you. Can't believe I made a rookie mistake like that. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can one of you add it as an official answer? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `relatedTo` parameter can take an object, an element ID or an array of element objects and/or IDs. In your case the latter is expected so wrapping your arguments in an array should fix the issue:

```twig
{% set entries = craft
                .entries
                .section('survivorAssets')
                .relatedTo(['and',{ targetElement: theme },{ targetElement: survivor }])
                .orderBy('assetOrder')
                .all() %}
```